# Compiling a Fortran file with gfortran 4.1.1 on a PC

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I am trying to run a couple of fixed-formatted Fortran 90 files on a PC. They run flawlessly with gfortran version 4.1.1, but not with gfortran 4.1.2 or later (I tried). Here are all the things I've tried:

1. I tried using the tag "-std=legacy" in Cygwin with version 4.9.3 so the processor compiles the code as a Fortran 77 file. I had to work out some kinks, but eventually it began to work splendidly. Then the following error popped up:

   > Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_INVALID_FLAG IEEE_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO IEEE_OVERFLOW_FLAG IEEE_DENORMAL

   I then moved on to plan B: trying to get gfortran 4.1.1 on my PC, on Cygwin.
2. Building gfortran 4.1.1 from source in Cygwin (since I can't find binary files anywhere online). Cygwin already has a package for gfortran, but only version 4.9.3. I used gcc-fortran-4.1.1.tar.bz2; basically I want to downgrade gfortran in Cygwin. the files in the tarball were lacking so I had to debug some things and add some files with some wget's (like the most current versions of config.guess and config.sub) to get it to configure (I also used autoconf, autoreconf, and automake). Long story short, I tried to run make and I got a long list of errors.

   I have access to a Linux machine with gfortran 4.1.1 already on it (on which it works perfectly), and tried to make it there, but it gave a lot of errors as well, completely different from those from Cygwin. At the end are the errors, the first being those from Cygwin and the latter from Linux. I access the Linux computer remotely via SSH; the entire point of this endeavor is to run the codes on PC's (and/or Mac's) so that we don't have to transfer thousands of images and files back and forth.
3. I tried to download g95  onto Cygwin via the tarball g95-x86-cygwin-41.tgz found online. The INSTALL file said I just need to extract the files in the root directory, create a symbolic link somewhere, and it should work. I did and then I typed it in and nothing happened; no "-bash: ... No such file or directory" error or other errors, but simply nothing. No executable was created-nothing. I even mispelled --version and no error popped up.

   ```
   J Double B@jdoubleb-PC /wexlerwork/autismcases_CTs/autismcases_23_VOID
   $ g95 --versio

   J Double B@jdoubleb-PC /wexlerwork/autismcases_CTs/autismcases_23_VOID
   $ g95 --version

   J Double B@jdoubleb-PC /wexlerwork/autismcases_CTs/autismcases_23_VOID
   $ g95 --help

   J Double B@jdoubleb-PC /wexlerwork/autismcases_CTs/autismcases_23_VOID
   $ man g95
   No manual entry for g95

   J Double B@jdoubleb-PC /wexlerwork/autismcases_CTs/autismcases_23_VOID
   $ g95 ver5.2_v3.5.f -o f05

   J Double B@jdoubleb-PC /wexlerwork/autismcases_CTs/autismcases_23_VOID
   ```

   I even tried the self-extracting files for gcc 4.1 from the following website: http://g95.org/downloads.shtml. I tried the HTTP link and it gave me the tarball I mentioned above. I tried the FTP link and it did nothing useful.
4. I tried g95 via MinGW and my Windows 7 command shell (from the Start menu). It was an executable, so it was nice to not have to build it. It downloaded and it works. However, there are a lot of errors. It didn't recognize all the comments beginning with 'c', so I changed them all to !'s. Then the compiler mentioned continuations. There are hundreds of continuations in the code, and only a limited amount are allowed per version and format type I think. Essentially the compiler processes Fortran 95 files (naturally-it's in the name), but the file is not a Fortran file. I tried to pass a "-std=legacy" or something similar, but apparently the only options are for Fortran 95, 2003, and 2008. It'd take forever to change a 7000-line and a 3000-line Fortran 77/90 file to Fortran 95 files, so I stopped. Well, I figured I'd give it a try.
5. I tried changing the extensions of the files to *.f90, but they were interpreted by my computer to be Fortran 95 files and it didn't work.

I'd rather not continue to try and change the codes so they work for some kind of compiler, but rather simply get gfortran 4.1.1 on my computer and have them running just like on the Linux computer. I'd also like to not have to build anything from source-executables for Fortran compilers are welcome. However, I'm not completely closed to the prospect.

Any help from anyone is welcome; thank you in advance for your consideration.

```
*FROM CYGWIN*
J Double B@jdoubleb-PC /gcc-4.1.1
$ make
cat: libgfortran/../gcc/BASE-VER: No such file or directory
makefile:2442: warning: overriding commands for target `.F90.o'
makefile:1059: warning: ignoring old commands for target `.F90.o'
makefile:2445: warning: overriding commands for target `.F90.obj'
makefile:1062: warning: ignoring old commands for target `.F90.obj'
makefile:2448: warning: overriding commands for target `.F90.lo'
makefile:1065: warning: ignoring old commands for target `.F90.lo'
C:/Users/jdoubleb/Documents/Academia/Cygwin_etal/bin/sh.exe libgfortran/mk-kinds-h.sh ' -I . -Wall -fno-repack-arrays -fno-underscoring ' > kinds.h || rm kinds.h
grep '^#' < kinds.h > kinds.inc
grep '^#' < libgfortran/c99_protos.h > c99_protos.inc
cp libgfortran/config/fpu-glibc.h fpu-target.h
C:/Ch/bin/make  all-am
cat: libgfortran/../gcc/BASE-VER: No such file or directory
make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Users/jdoubleb/Documents/Academia/Cygwin_etal/gcc-4.1.1'
makefile:2442: warning: overriding commands for target `.F90.o'
makefile:1059: warning: ignoring old commands for target `.F90.o'
makefile:2445: warning: overriding commands for target `.F90.obj'
makefile:1062: warning: ignoring old commands for target `.F90.obj'
makefile:2448: warning: overriding commands for target `.F90.lo'
makefile:1065: warning: ignoring old commands for target `.F90.lo'
C:/Users/jdoubleb/Documents/Academia/Cygwin_etal/bin/sh.exe ./libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -Ilibgfortran -I.  -iquotelibgfortran/io -Ilibgfortran/../gcc -Ilibgfortran/../gcc/config -I../.././gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE  -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -Wunknown-pragmas -c -o compile_options.lo `test -f 'runtime/compile_options.c' || echo 'libgfortran/'`runtime/compile_options.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -Ilibgfortran -I. -iquotelibgfortran/io -Ilibgfortran/../gcc -Ilibgfortran/../gcc/config -I../.././gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -Wunknown-pragmas -c libgfortran/runtime/compile_options.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/compile_options.o
In file included from libgfortran/runtime/compile_options.c:32:0:
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:204:9: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_INTEGER_4’
 typedef GFC_INTEGER_4 gfc_charlen_type;
         ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:254:51: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_INTEGER_4’
 typedef GFC_ARRAY_DESCRIPTOR (GFC_MAX_DIMENSIONS, GFC_INTEGER_4) gfc_array_i4;
                                                   ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:245:3: note: in definition of macro ‘GFC_ARRAY_DESCRIPTOR’
   type *data;\
   ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:255:51: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_INTEGER_8’
 typedef GFC_ARRAY_DESCRIPTOR (GFC_MAX_DIMENSIONS, GFC_INTEGER_8) gfc_array_i8;
                                                   ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:245:3: note: in definition of macro ‘GFC_ARRAY_DESCRIPTOR’
   type *data;\
   ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:259:51: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_REAL_4’
 typedef GFC_ARRAY_DESCRIPTOR (GFC_MAX_DIMENSIONS, GFC_REAL_4) gfc_array_r4;
                                                   ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:245:3: note: in definition of macro ‘GFC_ARRAY_DESCRIPTOR’
   type *data;\
   ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:260:51: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_REAL_8’
 typedef GFC_ARRAY_DESCRIPTOR (GFC_MAX_DIMENSIONS, GFC_REAL_8) gfc_array_r8;
                                                   ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:245:3: note: in definition of macro ‘GFC_ARRAY_DESCRIPTOR’
   type *data;\
   ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:267:51: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_COMPLEX_4’
 typedef GFC_ARRAY_DESCRIPTOR (GFC_MAX_DIMENSIONS, GFC_COMPLEX_4) gfc_array_c4;
                                                   ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:245:3: note: in definition of macro ‘GFC_ARRAY_DESCRIPTOR’
   type *data;\
   ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:268:51: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_COMPLEX_8’
 typedef GFC_ARRAY_DESCRIPTOR (GFC_MAX_DIMENSIONS, GFC_COMPLEX_8) gfc_array_c8;
                                                   ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:245:3: note: in definition of macro ‘GFC_ARRAY_DESCRIPTOR’
   type *data;\
   ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:275:51: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_LOGICAL_4’
 typedef GFC_ARRAY_DESCRIPTOR (GFC_MAX_DIMENSIONS, GFC_LOGICAL_4) gfc_array_l4;
                                                   ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:245:3: note: in definition of macro ‘GFC_ARRAY_DESCRIPTOR’
   type *data;\
   ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:276:51: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_LOGICAL_8’
 typedef GFC_ARRAY_DESCRIPTOR (GFC_MAX_DIMENSIONS, GFC_LOGICAL_8) gfc_array_l8;
                                                   ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:245:3: note: in definition of macro ‘GFC_ARRAY_DESCRIPTOR’
   type *data;\
   ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:456:51: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘char’
 extern const char *gfc_itoa (GFC_INTEGER_LARGEST, char *, size_t);
                                                   ^
In file included from libgfortran/runtime/compile_options.c:32:0:
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:457:16: error: ‘gfc_itoa’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 internal_proto(gfc_itoa);
                ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:79:52: note: in definition of macro ‘sym_rename2’
 #define sym_rename2(old, ulp, new) extern __typeof(old) old __asm__(#ulp #new)
                                                    ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:77:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘sym_rename1’
 #define sym_rename(old, new) sym_rename1(old, __USER_LABEL_PREFIX__, new)
                              ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:120:28: note: in expansion of macro ‘sym_rename’
 # define internal_proto(x) sym_rename(x, IPREFIX(x))
                            ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:457:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘internal_proto’
 internal_proto(gfc_itoa);
 ^
In file included from libgfortran/runtime/compile_options.c:32:0:
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:459:48: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘char’
 extern const char *xtoa (GFC_UINTEGER_LARGEST, char *, size_t);
                                                ^
In file included from libgfortran/runtime/compile_options.c:32:0:
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:460:16: error: ‘xtoa’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 internal_proto(xtoa);
                ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:79:52: note: in definition of macro ‘sym_rename2’
 #define sym_rename2(old, ulp, new) extern __typeof(old) old __asm__(#ulp #new)
                                                    ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:77:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘sym_rename1’
 #define sym_rename(old, new) sym_rename1(old, __USER_LABEL_PREFIX__, new)
                              ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:120:28: note: in expansion of macro ‘sym_rename’
 # define internal_proto(x) sym_rename(x, IPREFIX(x))
                            ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:460:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘internal_proto’
 internal_proto(xtoa);
 ^
In file included from libgfortran/runtime/compile_options.c:32:0:
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:550:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
 extern void stop_numeric (GFC_INTEGER_4);
 ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:563:1: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_INTEGER_4’
 GFC_INTEGER_4 *internal_pack_4 (gfc_array_i4 *);
 ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:566:1: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_INTEGER_8’
 GFC_INTEGER_8 *internal_pack_8 (gfc_array_i8 *);
 ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:574:1: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_COMPLEX_4’
 GFC_COMPLEX_4 *internal_pack_c4 (gfc_array_c4 *);
 ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:577:1: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_COMPLEX_8’
 GFC_COMPLEX_8 *internal_pack_c8 (gfc_array_c8 *);
 ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:585:54: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_INTEGER_4’
 extern void internal_unpack_4 (gfc_array_i4 *, const GFC_INTEGER_4 *);
                                                      ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:588:54: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_INTEGER_8’
 extern void internal_unpack_8 (gfc_array_i8 *, const GFC_INTEGER_8 *);
                                                      ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:596:55: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_COMPLEX_4’
 extern void internal_unpack_c4 (gfc_array_c4 *, const GFC_COMPLEX_4 *);
                                                       ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:599:55: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_COMPLEX_8’
 extern void internal_unpack_c8 (gfc_array_c8 *, const GFC_COMPLEX_8 *);
                                                       ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:609:8: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_INTEGER_4’
 extern GFC_INTEGER_4 compare_string (GFC_INTEGER_4, const char *,
        ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:609:53: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
 extern GFC_INTEGER_4 compare_string (GFC_INTEGER_4, const char *,
                                                     ^
In file included from libgfortran/runtime/compile_options.c:32:0:
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:611:15: error: ‘compare_string’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 iexport_proto(compare_string);
               ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:79:52: note: in definition of macro ‘sym_rename2’
 #define sym_rename2(old, ulp, new) extern __typeof(old) old __asm__(#ulp #new)
                                                    ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:77:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘sym_rename1’
 #define sym_rename(old, new) sym_rename1(old, __USER_LABEL_PREFIX__, new)
                              ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:139:26: note: in expansion of macro ‘sym_rename’
 # define export_proto(x) sym_rename(x, PREFIX(x))
                          ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:141:27: note: in expansion of macro ‘export_proto’
 # define iexport_proto(x) export_proto(x)
                           ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:611:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘iexport_proto’
 iexport_proto(compare_string);
 ^
In file included from libgfortran/runtime/compile_options.c:32:0:
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:615:26: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_INTEGER_4’
 extern void random_seed (GFC_INTEGER_4 * size, gfc_array_i4 * put,
                          ^
In file included from libgfortran/runtime/compile_options.c:32:0:
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:617:15: error: ‘random_seed’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 iexport_proto(random_seed);
               ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:79:52: note: in definition of macro ‘sym_rename2’
 #define sym_rename2(old, ulp, new) extern __typeof(old) old __asm__(#ulp #new)
                                                    ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:77:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘sym_rename1’
 #define sym_rename(old, new) sym_rename1(old, __USER_LABEL_PREFIX__, new)
                              ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:139:26: note: in expansion of macro ‘sym_rename’
 # define export_proto(x) sym_rename(x, PREFIX(x))
                          ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:141:27: note: in expansion of macro ‘export_proto’
 # define iexport_proto(x) export_proto(x)
                           ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:617:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘iexport_proto’
 iexport_proto(random_seed);
 ^
In file included from libgfortran/runtime/compile_options.c:32:0:
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:621:8: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_REAL_4’
 extern GFC_REAL_4 normalize_r4_i4 (GFC_UINTEGER_4, GFC_UINTEGER_4);
        ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:621:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
 extern GFC_REAL_4 normalize_r4_i4 (GFC_UINTEGER_4, GFC_UINTEGER_4);
 ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:624:8: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_REAL_8’
 extern GFC_REAL_8 normalize_r8_i8 (GFC_UINTEGER_8, GFC_UINTEGER_8);
        ^
libgfortran/libgfortran.h:624:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
 extern GFC_REAL_8 normalize_r8_i8 (GFC_UINTEGER_8, GFC_UINTEGER_8);
 ^
libgfortran/runtime/compile_options.c:40:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
 extern void set_std (GFC_INTEGER_4, GFC_INTEGER_4, GFC_INTEGER_4);
 ^
libgfortran/runtime/compile_options.c:45:10: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_INTEGER_4’
 set_std (GFC_INTEGER_4 warn_std, GFC_INTEGER_4 allow_std,
          ^
libgfortran/runtime/compile_options.c:45:34: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_INTEGER_4’
 set_std (GFC_INTEGER_4 warn_std, GFC_INTEGER_4 allow_std,
                                  ^
libgfortran/runtime/compile_options.c:46:3: error: unknown type name ‘GFC_INTEGER_4’
   GFC_INTEGER_4 pedantic)
   ^
libgfortran/runtime/compile_options.c: In function ‘set_record_marker’:
libgfortran/runtime/compile_options.c:89:19: error: ‘GFC_INTEGER_4’ undeclared (first use in this function)
       if (sizeof (GFC_INTEGER_4) != sizeof (gfc_offset))
                   ^
libgfortran/runtime/compile_options.c:89:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
libgfortran/runtime/compile_options.c:94:19: error: ‘GFC_INTEGER_8’ undeclared (first use in this function)
       if (sizeof (GFC_INTEGER_8) != sizeof (gfc_offset))
                   ^
make[1]: *** [compile_options.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/jdoubleb/Documents/Academia/Cygwin_etal/gcc-4.1.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2

J Double B@jdoubleb-PC /gcc-4.1.1












*FROM LINUX*
[wexlerlab@AirWay~/Jeremiah/gcc-fortran-4.1.1/gcc-4.1.1 ]$ make 
cat: libgfortran/../gcc/BASE-VER: No such file or directory
/bin/sh libgfortran/mk-sik-inc.sh 'gfortran -I . -Wall -fno-repack-arrays -fno-underscoring -g -O2' > selected_int_kind.inc || rm selected_int_kind.inc
/bin/sh libgfortran/mk-srk-inc.sh 'gfortran -I . -Wall -fno-repack-arrays -fno-underscoring -g -O2' > selected_real_kind.inc || rm selected_real_kind.inc
/bin/sh libgfortran/mk-kinds-h.sh 'gfortran -I . -Wall -fno-repack-arrays -fno-underscoring -g -O2' > kinds.h || rm kinds.h
grep '^#' < kinds.h > kinds.inc
grep '^#' < libgfortran/c99_protos.h > c99_protos.inc
cp libgfortran/config/fpu-glibc.h fpu-target.h
make  all-am
cat: libgfortran/../gcc/BASE-VER: No such file or directory
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/wexlerlab/Jeremiah/gcc-fortran-4.1.1/gcc-4.1.1'
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -Ilibgfortran -I.  -iquotelibgfortran/io -Ilibgfortran/../gcc -Ilibgfortran/../gcc/config -I../.././gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE  -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wextra -Wwrite-strings  -c -o compile_options.lo `test -f 'runtime/compile_options.c' || echo 'libgfortran/'`runtime/compile_options.c
mkdir .libs
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -Ilibgfortran -I. -iquotelibgfortran/io -Ilibgfortran/../gcc -Ilibgfortran/../gcc/config -I../.././gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -c libgfortran/runtime/compile_options.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/compile_options.o
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -Ilibgfortran -I. -iquotelibgfortran/io -Ilibgfortran/../gcc -Ilibgfortran/../gcc/config -I../.././gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -c libgfortran/runtime/compile_options.c -o compile_options.o >/dev/null 2>&1
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -Ilibgfortran -I.  -iquotelibgfortran/io -Ilibgfortran/../gcc -Ilibgfortran/../gcc/config -I../.././gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE  -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wextra -Wwrite-strings  -c -o environ.lo `test -f 'runtime/environ.c' || echo 'libgfortran/'`runtime/environ.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -Ilibgfortran -I. -iquotelibgfortran/io -Ilibgfortran/../gcc -Ilibgfortran/../gcc/config -I../.././gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -c libgfortran/runtime/environ.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/environ.o
In file included from libgfortran/runtime/environ.c:37:
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:36:18: error: gthr.h: No such file or directory
In file included from libgfortran/runtime/environ.c:37:
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:504: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before '__gthread_mutex_t'
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:699: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'unit_lock'
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:700: error: 'unit_lock' undeclared here (not in a function)
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:700: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'unit_lock'
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h: In function 'inc_waiting_locked':
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:890: error: 'gfc_unit' has no member named 'waiting'
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:890: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of '__sync_fetch_and_add'
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h: In function 'predec_waiting_locked':
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:900: error: 'gfc_unit' has no member named 'waiting'
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:900: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of '__sync_add_and_fetch'
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:904: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h: In function 'dec_waiting_unlocked':
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:910: error: 'gfc_unit' has no member named 'waiting'
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:910: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of '__sync_fetch_and_add'
make[1]: *** [environ.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/wexlerlab/Jeremiah/gcc-fortran-4.1.1/gcc-4.1.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
[wexlerlab@AirWay~/Jeremiah/gcc-fortran-4.1.1/gcc-4.1.1 ]$ cd libgfortran/
[wexlerlab@AirWay~/Jeremiah/gcc-fortran-4.1.1/gcc-4.1.1/libgfortran ]$ automake
[wexlerlab@AirWay~/Jeremiah/gcc-fortran-4.1.1/gcc-4.1.1/libgfortran ]$ cd..
-bash: cd..: command not found
[wexlerlab@AirWay~/Jeremiah/gcc-fortran-4.1.1/gcc-4.1.1/libgfortran ]$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
[wexlerlab@AirWay~/Jeremiah/gcc-fortran-4.1.1/gcc-4.1.1/libgfortran ]$ cd ..
[wexlerlab@AirWay~/Jeremiah/gcc-fortran-4.1.1/gcc-4.1.1 ]$ make
cat: libgfortran/../gcc/BASE-VER: No such file or directory
 cd . && /bin/sh ./config.status Makefile 
config.status: creating Makefile
cat: libgfortran/../gcc/BASE-VER: No such file or directory
make  all-am
cat: libgfortran/../gcc/BASE-VER: No such file or directory
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/wexlerlab/Jeremiah/gcc-fortran-4.1.1/gcc-4.1.1'
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -Ilibgfortran -I.  -iquotelibgfortran/io -Ilibgfortran/../gcc -Ilibgfortran/../gcc/config -I../.././gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE  -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wextra -Wwrite-strings  -c -o environ.lo `test -f 'runtime/environ.c' || echo 'libgfortran/'`runtime/environ.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -Ilibgfortran -I. -iquotelibgfortran/io -Ilibgfortran/../gcc -Ilibgfortran/../gcc/config -I../.././gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -c libgfortran/runtime/environ.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/environ.o
In file included from libgfortran/runtime/environ.c:37:
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:36:18: error: gthr.h: No such file or directory
In file included from libgfortran/runtime/environ.c:37:
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:504: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before '__gthread_mutex_t'
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:699: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'unit_lock'
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:700: error: 'unit_lock' undeclared here (not in a function)
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:700: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'unit_lock'
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h: In function 'inc_waiting_locked':
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:890: error: 'gfc_unit' has no member named 'waiting'
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:890: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of '__sync_fetch_and_add'
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h: In function 'predec_waiting_locked':
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:900: error: 'gfc_unit' has no member named 'waiting'
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:900: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of '__sync_add_and_fetch'
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:904: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h: In function 'dec_waiting_unlocked':
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:910: error: 'gfc_unit' has no member named 'waiting'
libgfortran/runtime/../io/io.h:910: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of '__sync_fetch_and_add'
make[1]: *** [environ.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/wexlerlab/Jeremiah/gcc-fortran-4.1.1/gcc-4.1.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
[wexlerlab@AirWay~/Jeremiah/gcc-fortran-4.1.1/gcc-4.1.1 ]$
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, I don't have the time to read through all of this :( Please, narrow it down! You should read [ask] and provide a concise minimum example.

Comment: Please, make a short concise question and include a small piece of code which exhibits the problem.

Comment: Having flicked through the above I would strongly suggest that you would be better off working out why it's not working with 4.9.3, rather than trying to install the (very old) 4.1.1. The signals you mention above suggest to me that there are bugs in the code, bugs that 4.1.1 is just not picking up - as such I wouldn't trust the results from the 4.1.1 executable until I understood why the code isn't working with 4.9.3

Comment: It seems like you should focus on (1) - why is the code failing with a modern compiler? You should debug the code and find out why it errors.

Comment: Sorry about the long question; I saw that I should research the topic myself before asking, and I wanted to convey that. Perhaps I did so too much though...I'll look into that - debugging the code for now. @IanBush: I hadn't realized that; I'll try and look into that. Thank you all for your input.

Comment: The question is not that bad in my opinion. Maybe to much information but you clearly see what the OP tried and the effort that has been put in the solving the question.

Comment: Could you try compiling with -fcheck=all or -fbounds-check (for gfortran)? The option may be different for gfortran4.1.1, so pls check the man page for similar ones. It might show, e.g., an error like "accessing element 0" etc.

Comment: @ roygvib, I tried that and nothing showed up. In fact, the codes worked in Cygwin after all; I happened to try using faulty inputs unknowingly, so I tried different inputs and they worked. The compiler still noted math errors, but all the outputs were made successfully. I think this issue is solved.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your help!